# Hardy-Littlewood theorem about the Poisson integral for $p=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, hardy-spaces

(Hardy-Littlewood Theorem) : Let ‎$ u(r,‎\theta)‎$‎ be the Poisson integral of
‎$ ‎\varphi ‎\in L‎^{p}‎‎$‎, ‎$ 1<P ‎\leqslant‎ ‎\infty‎$‎ , and let $ U(‎\theta)=\sup‎_{r<1}‎|u(r,‎\theta)|‎ $‎.

Then $ ‎U ‎\in L‎^{p}‎‎$, and there is a constant $A‎_{p}‎ $ depending only on $p$ such that  ‎‎$ ‎\Vert ‎U‎\Vert‎_{P}‎‎‎ ‎\leqslant A‎_{p}‎   ‎\Vert ‎\varphi ‎\Vert‎_{P}‎‎‎‎‎$‎.

The proof of theorem is easy. But my question is why for $p=1$ Theorem is False.
I try to use the modified Poisson kernel $ u(r,‎\theta)= ‎\dfrac{R^2-r^2}{R^2-2R r   \cos‎\theta+r^2}‎‎$ for $R>1$. I use max and min $ u(r,‎\theta)‎$ but I can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea to use $$u(r,‎\theta)= ‎\dfrac{R^2-r^2}{R^2-2R r   \cos‎\theta+r^2}$$‎‎
is a good one. Let's take $|\theta|$ small but greater than $R-1$; also let $r=1-|\theta|$. Then the denominator can be estimated as 
$$R^2-2R r   \cos‎\theta+r^2 \le 10|\theta|^2$$
since it's the squared distance between points with polar coordinates $(R,0)$ and $(r,\theta)$. (I use $10$ to say there's some factor there, but it's fixed.)

On the other hand, $R^2-r^2=(R-r)(R+r)\ge |\theta|$. Conclusion: 
$$
U(\theta) \ge\frac{1}{10 |\theta|},\quad |\theta|>R-1
$$ 
and this shows that the $L^1$ norm of $U$ blows up as $R\to 1$, while  the $L^1$ norm of $u(1,\cdot)$ remains $1$.

Comment: thanks for your help. but why
$R^2−2Rr cos‎θ+r^2≤10|θ|^2$

Comment: You didn't think of it for long enough. Draw the points with polar coordinates $(R,0)$ and $(r,\theta)$.

Comment: can I use a constant such as K instead 10? since I understand why is 10.

Comment: Yes, write $K$ if you prefer. I could put $6252$ instead of $10$ there.'